# JPARepository's findbyid returns null even though db object exists (Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Calls to findById(id) return null, even though I am 100% sure the item exists in the database with the same id.

My repository class:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends Repository<Item, String>, JpaRepository<Item, String>
```

My main class:

```
 itemRepository.findById(input.getItemId()).get();
```

Note, this question may sound similar to [Spring boot JPA no returning existing result using findById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60189890/spring-boot-jpa-no-returning-existing-result-using-findbyid) but in his case the data would never return, regardless of how many time he called findById. For me, in my debugger if I evaluate the line containing `findById` twice, on the second try I get the result from the database.

- Since I can eventually get the object, it means that I am pointing to the correct database.
- I am not using @Cache anywhere in my codebase
- The data either comes back as the correct db record, or as null - never as corrupt/dirty data
- I am not using @Async JPA operations

Would appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction on how to isolate this issue. Or if this is a known JPA bug.

EDIT - picture showing result of the same line of code before and after clicking "execute" twice. Notice the result is null the first time, and the result has a real value the second time.

[image: On initial debug evaluation]

And after clicking evaluate a second time:

[image]

My application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/myDb?useSSL=false
# Hibernate config
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
```

Comment: Can you paste the code?

Comment: How did you make sure an entity with given id exists in the database?

Comment: I added a breakpoint on that line, and manually ran the line using the Intellij evaluator, which returns my db object correctly after running it twice.

Comment: So it works in your debugger? Are you sure it's this line, that causes the error?

Comment: Well I don't get an error - its just that I'm expecting a value to be returned, but I'm getting null instead.

Comment: Does the line return the value (as expected) in the debugger?

Comment: Yes it does, on the second time I press `execute` in my debug evaluator console.

Comment: If it isn't returning anything there is nothing to return. The result doesn't lie. So you are either not connecting to the database you are looking at and reading from, or the id you are using isn't the Id you are expecting to use. The fact that the second one is returning a result, is probably due to flushing somewhere in between. Add your configuration and setup to your question.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I understand what you're saying but how can I be pointing to the wrong database if I am able to receive the value from the database by simple running the same line of code twice? If I was pointing to the wrong db, or had the wrong id, then I shouldn't receive any value regardless of how many times I ran line of code for retrieving this db object. I am however interested in your idea that its being flushed somewhere in between - do you know if JPA does some sort of flushing after an initial call to a JpaRepository method (`findById` in my case.

Comment: Depending on your flushmode it might flush before a select. Also how is the record getting into the database? Has that process ended already? How is your transactionallity for this (or other methods).

Comment: I am manually inserting that record using the Intellij MySQL db console. I run my code once the manual insert is complete (only takes a fraction of second to insert). What does "transactionality" mean? Also I do not set the flushmode manually, since I'm not using entityManager nor a persistence.xml file - all annotation based configuration.